# Routing traffic away from a VPN connection

Tags: vpn, route

I'm using a VPN which takes all my traffic by default. For some addresses, I'd like my computer to avoid using the VPN as it is slowing down the quality of the connection. The addresses for the service are 13.107.64.0/18, 52.112.0.0/14 and 52.120.0.0/14

I'm trying to use the `route` command to set this up but it doesn't like the subnet mask that's provided here:

```
# sudo route add 52.112.0.0/14 gw 192.168.1.1 metric 600
route: netmask 0003ffff doesn't make sense with host route
```

What command can I use to reroute this traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding net routes, you should specify the `-net` switch to the `route` command, as the default setting wants to deal with single-host routes, to which specifying a netmask indeed doesn't make sense. So use either this command:

```
sudo route add -net 52.112.0.0/14 gw 192.168.1.1 metric 600
```

or use the `ip` command (`route` is deprecated anyway), which can determine the route type from the netmask you give:

```
sudo ip route add 52.112.0.0/14 via 192.168.1.1 metric 600
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lacek. That solved my issue.